# How to get messages in a channel then delete them?

Tags: discord, pycord

### How to get a certain amount of messages in a channel to delete them (Pycord)

I want to create a /purge command to delete a certain amount of messages from a channel. Is there a way to get messages from a specific channel, and then delete them?

Note: A lot of the duplicates that were flagged are either from the wrong library or the wrong language entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the built-in library [`channel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.purge).

Or the less suitable [`async for ... in channel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.history).

In both cases, you need to make some sort of checking function.